# Is a CSE masters deemed too similar to a masters in maths?

Tags: education

I have a masters in maths and have been working in industry for a couple of years. Since I specialized more towards pure maths during my studies (theoretical PDEs), I have found myself needing to pick up many computational skills when I started working. Now, I have gained an interest in computational problem solving and I am now very much interested in pursuing further education in this area (in particular fluid mechanics).

I know that most masters programmes will not admit a student who already has a masters degree in a very similar field (e.g. pure math and applied math). My question is, does CSE and math fall in this category?

Comment: Write to the department where you intend to apply and ask.

Comment: The answer will depend strongly on the particular program.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that most masters programmes will not admit a student who
> already has a masters degree in a very similar field (e.g. pure math
> and applied math)

I'm a CSE Master's student in Germany and I've met a lot of peers who already have a previous Master's degree. I suggest just go apply and craft your motivation letter to make a convincing argument why you're suited to the program. With your background plus a strong motivation letter you'll have a high chance to get into CSE. After all, for a maths-heavy field like CSE it would be a huge loss if students with maths background are filtered out!